# pandas groupby filter nunique

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So far an example of what I have is here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"barcode": [1,2,2,3,3,4, 4, 4], "date": ['today', 'today', 'tomorrow', 'tomorrow', 'tomorrow', 'yesterday', 'yesterday' ,'yesterday'], "info": [40,20,10,15,17,19, 21, 23]}) 
gb= df.groupby(['date'])
gb.filter(lambda x: x['barcode'].nunique!=1)
```

which returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [barcode, date, info]
Index: []
```

Only "yesterday" should remain after I filter this because there are 2 distinct barcodes in the group "today", and 2 distinct barcodes in the group "tomorrow".  What is going on here?  and in the example the column to filter on is sorted but does it need to be?

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend

```
gb= df.groupby(['date'])
df = df[gb['barcode'].transform('nunqiue').eq(1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`nunique` is a method, not a property. Fix:

```
gb.filter(lambda x: x['barcode'].nunique() ==1)
```